# How to have two pull-right elements one below another in bootstrap grid system?

Tags: html, css

I have a bootstrap grid system on my page and want two elements pulled to the right, but placed one below the other. This is the code I have right now. I want "Active" and "Primary" button place one below the other, but also pulled right. As of now, it looks like this:
[image]

If I were to add this to the button, then it aligns properly, but on mobile, it messes up.

`<button type="button" class="btn btn-w-m btn-primary" style="margin-left: 261px;">Primary</button>`

[image]

This is what I have so far. What can I do to achieve the desired result?

```
<div class="wrapper wrapper-content  animated fadeInRight">
    <div class="row  border-bottom white-bg dashboard-header">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <h4>Dummy Name</h4>
            <small>Dummy Street</small><br>
            <small>Dummy Apt, Some City, Some State</small><br>
            <small>United States</small><br>
        </div>


        <div class="col-md-3">
            <h5>123-456-7890</h5>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <h5>some_name@somecompany.com</h5>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <h2 class="pull-right" style="margin-top: -5px">Active</h2><br>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-w-m btn-primary">Primary</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need pull-right at all - all you need to right align the text of the heading and the button is **text-align:right** in the css or the **text-right** class on the parent div. **Note that you need to open this snippet in "full screen mode due to the small size of the preview window.**

I would also suggest that you put the css in its own style sheet rather than inline style rules. If you use text-align: right as a style rule then you can use a media query to apply it or left align on certain screen sizes as required.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  
<div class="container"> 
  <div class="wrapper wrapper-content  animated fadeInRight">
    <div class="row  border-bottom white-bg dashboard-header">
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3">
            <h4>Dummy Name</h4>
            <small>Dummy Street</small><br>
            <small>Dummy Apt, Some City, Some State</small><br>
            <small>United States</small><br>
        </div>


        <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3">
            <h5>123-456-7890</h5>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3">
            <h5>some_name@somecompany.com</h5>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 text-right">
            <h2>Active</h2><br>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-w-m btn-primary">Primary</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```